# Make a regex not match if a certain string is found in the match?

Tags: c#, regex

Lets say i have some random easy match like

```
\bword\b
```

Now i want to add to this that if before this match there is lets say this

```
(HOUSE[ ]*?)\bword\b
```

So if the word HOUSE and whatever ammount of spaces is infront of word then the match should be false. So my question more or less is how do i negate the **(HOUSE[ ]*?)** query?

Comment: it seems unclear for me.

Comment: You use a negative lookbehind. In .NET lookbehinds can be infinite AFAIK so: `(?<!HOUSE[ ]*?)\bword\b` should do the job

Comment: yep. Post it as an answer.

Comment: +1 for @HamZa 's solution

Comment: @HamZa hm i think it will work but i was kinda trying to avoid lookarounds. Guess there is no other solution

Comment: @Vajura There should be another programmatic way. You use `(HOUSE[ ]*?)?\bword\b` and then check if group 1 exists. If it exists then the result should be false. Not sure how .NET handles the existence of group 1, but you could always check if it's empty or something like that.

Comment: @HamZa I actualy came up with excatly this 1 minute ago i think i prefer this solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You use a negative lookbehind. In .NET lookbehinds can be variable length:

```
(?<!HOUSE[ ]*?)\bword\b
```

**Reference**:

- [Variable length lookbehind](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20994257)